# Limit relationships

Tags: relationships

Is it possible to limit the number of relationships a contact might have?

For example, an organisation might have a "Secretary" relationship with an individual.

There can only be one of those.

So I don't want extra secretary relationships added to the organisationby accident.

Thanks as always.

Comment: It isn't possible via the UI so assume would have to be an extension. We did some work on this previously for a client but in the end they then changed their subscription logic so it was not needed. from a quick peruse of our notes it looks like it was working. (note to self 17031)

Answer (score 2):

As Pete has said, you can't do that with core Civi.  An alternative approach would be to create a 'Secretary' custom field on the Organisation as a Contact Reference.  That will ensure you can only have one.